# Crossed module correspondence to double groupoid

Tags: category-theory, groupoids

Reading Brown & Spencers papper on double groupoids and crossed modules I don't quite understand the constructed double groupoid(see http://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1976__17_4_343_0.pdf page 11)

Let $(A,B,\partial)$ be a crossed module, to construct the double groupoid of this crossed module we consider $E_0=1$(just some one point) $E_1=B$ and $E_2$ is the quintlet with $E_2=(\alpha,a,b,c,d\vert \partial(\alpha)=a^{-1}bcd^{-1}, \alpha\in A)$

I don't understand what the initial and final maps from $E_2$ to the two copies of $E_1$ are suppose to be, are we choosing arbitrary inital and final maps?(or source and target maps)

Answer (score 0):

The author's are a bit needlessly terse here, but if you look back to page to page 3, they represent squares labelled by $\alpha$ as quadruples: $(\partial_{0}\alpha,\epsilon_{0}\alpha,\partial_{1}\alpha,\epsilon_{1}\alpha)$ where each component labels an edge of the square starting from the left vertical edge and going around clockwise (I tried to input a diagram but I don't think MSE supports this, sorry!).

On page 11, they depict the boundary of a square $\alpha\in E_{2}$ (using such a quadruple as above) as $(a,b,c,d)$, i.e., $$\partial_{0}\alpha = a$$ and $$\partial_{1}\alpha = c$$ this is what is meant when they write that "the initial and final maps are just $\partial_{0}$ and $\partial_{1}$". This certainly makes sense too since, if we denote the "zero map for +" by $\iota$, we get that $$\partial_{0}\iota(a) = a = \partial_{1}\iota(a)$$ which is what one would hope for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So these are just abstract source and taget maps $\partial_0,\partial_1$ such that the diagram 'makes sense' not specific maps related to our crossed module?

Comment: No problem! These maps aren't coming directly from the crossed module structure. The deltas, epsilons, \circ, and + defined on p.11 give two (horizontal and vertical) groupoid structures on E_2 that interact. The fact that they form groupoid structures at all comes from one crossed module axiom, the fact that these groupoid structures interact "nicely" (the "interchange law") comes from the other crossed module axiom.